# Extrude 3d shape from THREE.Line object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js I have created an ellipseCurve for which I want to extrude and make 3d.

[image: ellipseCurve object]

**CODE USE TO MAKE THIS:**

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
0,  0,            // ax, aY
10, 13.3,           // xRadius, yRadius
0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
false,            // aClockwise
0                 // aRotation
);
var path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 100 ) );
var geometrycirc = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );
var materialcirc = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
 color : 0xff0000
 } );

// Create the final object to add to the scene
var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometrycirc, materialcirc );
this.scene.add( ellipse );
```

I want to use this ellipseCurve as a basis to create an extruded shape similar to these examples.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines

These examples seem to use vectors to do this, so I assume I need to convert the curve into one.

I am not sure how to do this since I have been unable to find references on this matter.

Any help to do this?

**UPDATE: 22/03/2017**

1. Right so I tried to implement the same method of extrusion as found on:
   https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines

[image: A simple closed spline]

2. I was able to but this spline into my scene:

[image: Spline in scene]

**HERE IS THE CODE TO DO THIS:**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //     My line curve                                                   //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
        0,  0,            // ax, aY
        10, 13.3,           // xRadius, yRadius
        0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
        false,            // aClockwise
        0                 // aRotation
    );

    var path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 100 ) );
    var geometrycirc = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );
    var materialcirc = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
        color : 0xff0000
    } );

    // Create the final object based on points and material
    var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometrycirc, materialcirc );
    this.scene.add( ellipse );



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //    Example of sample closed spine                                  //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var sampleClosedSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, -40, -40 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 40, -40 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 140, -40 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, 40, 40 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 0, -40, 40 )
    ] );


    sampleClosedSpline.type = 'catmullrom';
    sampleClosedSpline.closed = true;


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //     Extrusion method to covert the spline/vector data into 3d object     //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    // I used this method and have tried the following properties but these do not work
    //
    // var tube = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( curve, 12, 2, 20, true);
    //
    // 1. ellipse.clone()
    // 2. geometrycirc.clone()
    // 3. materialcirc.clone()
    // 4. path.clone()
    // 5. curve
    //
    // Therefore I am either doing something wrong or there must be a further process that needs
    // to be implemented.



    // this works as standard
    var tube = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( sampleClosedSpline, 12, 2, 20, true);


    var tubeMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( tube, [
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
            color: 0xffffff
        } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            color: 0xff00ff,
            opacity: 0.3,
            wireframe: true,
            transparent: true
        } ) ] );


    tubeMesh.scale.set( .2, .2, .2 );
    this.scene.add( tubeMesh );


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

3. So when I place the spline property for the one that I have created i get a black screen and the following error msgs:

var curve;
[image: curve error]

and the other variables used (refer to code to see what I have tried)
[image: other errors]

**EDIT: 23/03/2017**

WestLangley's method was the ideal solution

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried recreating the example you linked and plug in your curve in place of one of the splines?

Comment: @jered Tnxs for your input please look at my question again I have added screenshots, example code and thoughts to what i think is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a `TubeGeometry` or `TubeBufferGeometry` in the shape of an ellipse.

Here is one way to do it that is general enough for others to use, too.

First, create a new class that defines your path:

```js
// Ellipse class, which extends the virtual base class Curve
class Ellipse extends THREE.Curve {

    constructor( xRadius, yRadius ) {

        super();

        // add radius as a property
        this.xRadius = xRadius;
        this.yRadius = yRadius;


    }

    getPoint( t, optionalTarget = new THREE.Vector3() ) {

        const point = optionalTarget;
        var radians = 2 * Math.PI * t;

        return new THREE.Vector3( this.xRadius * Math.cos( radians ),
                                this.yRadius * Math.sin( radians ),
                                0 );


    }

}
```

Then create the geometry from the path.

```
// path
var path = new Ellipse( 5, 10 );

// params
var pathSegments = 64;
var tubeRadius = 0.5;
var radiusSegments = 16;
var closed = true;

var geometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( path, pathSegments, tubeRadius, radiusSegments, closed );
```

Super easy. :)

[image: ellipse rendering]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62qhxags/

three.js r.129

Comment: many thanks, I had a look at the three.js docs to findout the difference between `TubeGeometry` and `TubeBufferGeometry` to be honest they seem the same. I am only wanting to create one instance of this object so which of the two would you advise.

Comment: `TubeBufferGeometry` is more memory-efficient.